# C# HTML Agility Pack LoadHtml from string out of SQL Server Database

Tags: c#, html, .net, html-agility-pack

I have a database full of webpages that I want to extract information out of using the HTML agility pack. I have built a function that gets the information that I want when I load the text from a rich text box. However when I then load the HTML from a string out of the SQL Database, it is failing to get all of the text properly from the nodes. Therefore not giving me all the information I require from the webpage.

```
private static string[] Data(string strWebpage,string strURL, int iID)
        {
            //Declair and load HTML agility pack
            HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument HPD = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
            HPD.LoadHtml(strWebpage);


            string[] strData = new string[17];//Return string array

            //Get text from html nodes

                HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode HDNA = HPD.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='product_info']"); //Top product information
                HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode HDNB = HPD.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table[@width='300px']"); //Bottom Product Information
                HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode HDNC = HPD.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//h2[@class='name']"); //Product title
                HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode HDND = HPD.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='product_image']"); //Product URL
                HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode HDNE = HPD.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='contentwrapper']"); //Product Description
                HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNodeCollection HDNF = HPD.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='conttopright']//a[@class='uponelevel']"); //Get product category


            //Store temporary data ready to be processed and determined if useful
            List<string> strElimination = new List<string>();

                string[] strBits = TextToNArray(HDNA.InnerText);

                for (int i = 0; i < strBits.Length; i = i + 2)
                {
                    strElimination.Add(strBits[i].Trim() + "\t" + strBits[i + 1].Trim()); //Prepiar data types from field 1
                }


                string [] strBits = TextToNArray(HDNB.InnerText);

                for (int i = 0; i < strBits.Length; i = i + 2)
                {
                    strElimination.Add(strBits[i].Trim() + "\t" + strBits[i + 1].Trim()); //Prepiar data types from field 2
                }

            strData[13] = (HDNC.InnerText.Trim()); //Title
            strData[14] = (HDND.InnerHtml.Replace("\\", "\\\\").Replace("<img id=\"ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ProductImage\" src=\"", "").Replace("\" alt=\"Product Image\" style=\"border-width:0px;\">", "").Trim());
            strData[15] = strURL; //Page source URL
            strData[16] = iID.ToString(); //Raw page id
            strData[8] = ""; //Description start text
            strData[0] = ""; //Product category start text

            //Get product category
            foreach (var vCat in HDNF)
            {
                strData[0] += "-" + vCat.InnerText.ToString();
            }
            strData[0] = strData[0].Trim('-').Trim().Replace("Home-","");

            //Extract the description from the text
            string[] strDescProcess = TextToNArray(HDNE.InnerText);
            for (int i = 0; i < strDescProcess.Length; i++)
            {
                if(strDescProcess[i].Trim() == "Description")
                {
                    i++;
                    while (strDescProcess[i].Trim() != "More Product Details")
                    {
                        strData[8] += strDescProcess[i].Trim(); //Add description as one line
                        i++;
                    }
                }
            }

            //Order Additional information into array
            foreach (string strInfo in strElimination)
            {
                string [] strParts = strInfo.Split('\t');
                switch (strParts[0].Trim().ToLower())
                {
                    case "list price*":
                        double dPrice;
                        //Attempt to turn price into valid double value
                        try
                        {
                           dPrice  =  Convert.ToDouble(strParts[1].Substring(1));
                        }
                        catch
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                dPrice = Convert.ToDouble(strParts[1].Substring(2));
                            }
                            catch
                            {
                                dPrice = 0.0;
                            }
                        }
                        strData[1] = dPrice.ToString();
                        break;
                    case "availability":
                        //Determine if book is availiable
                        if (strParts[1].ToLower() == "available")
                        {
                            strData[2] = "1";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            strData[2] = "0";
                        }
                        break;
                    case "language":
                        strData[3] = strParts[1];
                        break;
                    case "arrangement":
                        strData[4] = strParts[1];
                        break;
                    case "skill level":
                        strData[5] = strParts[1];
                        break;
                    case "publisher":
                        strData[6] = strParts[1];
                        break;
                    case "catalogue no.":
                        strData[7] = strParts[1];
                        break;
                    case "published on":
                        //Turn the date into a format the database understands (American silly date format yyyy-MM-dd)
                        try
                        {
                            strData[9] = Convert.ToDateTime(strParts[1]).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
                        }
                        catch
                        {
                            //Date could not be parsed
                            strData[9] = "0000-00-00";
                        }
                        break;
                    case "format":
                        strData[10] = strParts[1];
                        break;
                    case "pages":
                        strData[11] = strParts[1];
                        break;
                    case "isbn":
                        strData[12] = strParts[1];
                        break;
                }
            }

            //Return data found
            return strData;
        }
```

Comment: Getting information from a database of from any other source is exactly the same. Same input string -> same results.

Comment: I get the same problem if I store the HTML source code in a string in C# when copied directly from the internet or stream the source in using streamreader from a local HTML file. However, if I copy the same source from either the database or directly from the internet, paste it into a rich textbox, then get the source from the rich textbox, text property it works perfectly.

Comment: Same story, you are not giving the same input in the two cases. Show us the input that fails and we may tell you why it fails. Note if you copy information given by a browser's view source, this is *not* the same as what the network will give you. Browsers run javascript code that changes HTML DOM in-memory.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Managed to fix it. For some reason the copy and paste was not adding extra blank lines that the database had in it. Managed to fix the problem by removing blank lines.